# on click checkbox, array loses its value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am invoking `a function` when we click on the checkbox and based on that clicking, I am pushing all the invoices which have pdf from a for loop by calling the url based on some row selected in the form. I console log the array and i am able to find the available invoices array, but somehow that array gets empty when i have a condition that if we have content in the array, we show a message. Is there something i am missing. Here is my code

isExist brings true or false. If its true we push that invoice in availableInvoicesPdf
if its false we push that value in noAvailableInvoicesPdf. `itemChecked` is `ng-model` binded with the checkbox

```
onChange() {
    this.availableInvoicesPdf = [];
    this.noAvailableInvoicesPdf = [];
    this.allPdfResponseAvailable = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.invoices.length; i += 1) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-loop-func
      this.Invoice.hasPdf(this.invoices[i].id).then((isExists) => { // calls a function which have a function hasPdf and takes id of the invoices selected to return back the response
        if (isExists) {
          this.availableInvoicesPdf.push({ //pushing invoice id and number for the invoices which have pdf available. I made sure that it had a pdf everytime.
            id: this.invoices[i].id,
            number: this.invoices[i].number
          });
        } else {
          this.noAvailableInvoicesPdf.push({
            number: this.invoices[i].number,
          });
        }
// i dont have value for available invoices pdf here. Somethinf weird if i console log it then i am able to see it, but when i debug, the array is empty.
      });
    }
    this.showSuccessMessage = false;
    this.noInvoiceMessage = false;
    if (this.itemChecked && this.availableInvoicesPdf.length === 0 && this.noAvailableInvoicesPdf.length === 0) { // i dont have value for available invoices pdf here 
      this.checkInvoicesHasPdf();
      console.log('after running invoice pdf', this.availableInvoicesPdf);
      if (this.availableInvoicesPdf.length > 0 && this.noAvailableInvoicesPdf.length > 0) { // i dont have value for available invoices pdf here 
        this.showSuccessMessage = true;
        this.noInvoiceMessage = true;
      } else if (this.availableInvoicesPdf.length > 0 && this.noAvailableInvoicesPdf.length === 0) { // i dont have value for available invoices pdf here 
        this.showSuccessMessage = true;
      } else if (this.availableInvoicesPdf.length === 0 && this.noAvailableInvoicesPdf.length > 0) { // i dont have value for available invoices pdf here 
        this.noInvoiceMessage = true;
      }
    } else {
      this.attachDefaultInvoice = this.itemChecked;
    }
}
```

Here is the hasPDF Code:

```
hasPdf(id) {
const url = `${this.ARConstant.EXPORTING_REST_API_URL}pdf/${id}`;
return this.$http.head(url)
  .then(() => true)
  .catch(() => false);
```

}

HTML:

```
<div class="pane-content" layout="column" ng-if="$ctrl.invoices.length <= 100">
    <div class="form-row" layout="row">
        <div class="attachPdf" flex="20">{{ 'attachPdf' | translate }}</div>
        <md-checkbox ng-disabled="$ctrl.isItaly" aria-label="{{ 'toAttach'| translate }}"
            class="attachPdf-cb md-primary" ng-model="$ctrl.itemChecked" ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()">
        </md-checkbox>
        <p ng-if="$ctrl.itemChecked && !$ctrl.allPdfResponseAvailable">{{ 'waitPdfUpload' | translate }} {{$ctrl.invoicesPdf.length}} /
            {{$ctrl.invoices.length}}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pane-content" layout="column" ng-if = "$ctrl.showSuccessMessage">
    <div class="form-row" layout="row">
        <div class="success-box-header-hidden" flex="20"></div>
        <div flex="80" class="success-message">
            <p class="success-text">
                <md-icon class="ionicons-svg-md-checkmark-circle" md-svg-src="img/ionicons-svg-md-checkmark-circle.svg"></md-icon>
                <span></span>Invoices PDF uploaded successfully</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the `hasPdf` code?

Comment: Sure. I updated the question !

Comment: `this.Invoice.hasPdf` is asynchronous and you are treating it as synchronous. You order pizza and you try to eat it before it is delivered to your house.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helped me. I read about async/await and now i get the pizza and then eat. :)